# What do the non-main threads do after I start a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

I have an application that basically just runs Main and exits (Console application, Visual Studio 2015), but If I set a breakpoint in main, and look at the threads I see the following:

[image: Threads]

I see that these threads are from different processes, why are they shown and not others? In what way are they related to my C# program? And in what cases would it be useful to know what these threads do?

Comment: What kind of an application is it? A console application? A Windows Form application?

Comment: You can view the thread activity in Profiler in the VS 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Windows applications have a WndProc message pump for windows OS to communicate with your application. In addition all .net applications have at least a GC Finalizer thread to destroy all the classes you create. vsHost is a VS.net debugger host that is wraps your application in and deals with the IO of the debugging and tracing data.

Comment: And the last two `<No Name>` threads are likely threadpool threads that got created with the start of the program.

Comment: What does thread with the ID 0 do(or did)? And why is there no GC Finalizer thread?

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork `0` thread could compile your application, or start it. One of unnamed threads can be a finalizer thread, other one could be GC thread.